# Unable to edit or delete schedule reports in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently getting the following error when editing and deleting scheduled reports in SSRS: "Only members of sysadmin role are allowed to update or delete jobs owned by a different login."

I've tried changing the owner of the jobs to the Service account used by SSRS, I've added that users as a sysadmin and I've checked the user and password for the limited account for the Reporting Services itself.  Nothing is making a difference.

The reporting services log just shows:

```
w3wp!library!a!06/03/2009-01:23:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Only members of sysadmin role are allowed to update or delete jobs owned by a different login.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InstrumentedSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SqlAgentScheduler.DeleteTask(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SchedulingDBInterface.UpdateTaskProperties(Task task, Boolean updateSqlAgentSchedule)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.TimedSubscriptionHandler.ValidateSubscriptionData(Subscription subscription, String subscriptionData, UserContext userContext)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SubscriptionManager.ValidateSubscriptionData(Subscription subscription, String eventType, String subscriptionData)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SubscriptionManager.SetSubscriptionProperties(Guid id, String eventType, String matchData, ExtensionSettings extensionSettings, String description, ParameterValueOrFieldReference[] parameters, DataRetrievalPlan dataSettings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SetSubscriptionPropertiesAction.PerformActionNow()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSSoapAction`1.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.  The SSRS application pool in IIS for the Reports Manager is running as the Network Service user, which was being used as the connection context even though the application using the service is loging in as the limited user.

Solutions:

- Change the application pool to a user that has SysAdmin rights or ownership of the jobs in the DB
- Or add the Network Service user as a SQL user and SysAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with SSRS 2005. 
Not all reports are like this but have struck the odd subscription that cannot be updated/removed.
IIS runs on one server as builtin network and the tables are on a separate clustered server. I cannot grant the IIS builtin account rights to the tables on the remote database server.
I have had some luck with finding the itemid of the report in the catalog, matching the report_oid in the subscriptions table and deleting the row with the affected subscription itemid.
Sounds awful but after this I can recreate the subscription and all is good in the world.